# Multiple Image Portfolios in the Ottavio template

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image

I am having trouble getting multiple Masonry type portfolios to work correctly on a webpage. For reference a Masonry type portfolio should look like this.
Here is an example from the templates site
(http://ottavio.kleis.agency/portfolio.html), 
if you can't view that page then essentially what it is, is a 4*3 image display where the 3 images on either side are of base size 1*1, and there are to images in the middle that are of sizes 2*2 and 2*1.

However when I try to add a second portfolio the second image down from the top left moves to the bottom of the portfolio and leaves white-space where it should be. 
[Which if the explanation wasn't clear looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcolu.jpg)

The code for the portfolio is this

```
        <section id="portfolio-gallery" data-folder="/portfolio" class="sep-top-md">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="filters" class="sep-bottom-lg">
          <button data-filter="*" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary upper">show all</button>
          <button data-filter=".branding" class="btn btn-sm upper">branding</button>
          <button data-filter=".design" class="btn btn-sm upper">design</button>
          <button data-filter=".photography" class="btn btn-sm upper">photography</button>
          <button data-filter=".videography" class="btn btn-sm upper">videography</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Start Ajax Section-->
      <div style="position:relative;" class="ajax-section section-gray">
        <div class="closeProject"><a href="#loader"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
        <div class="loader"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-2x"></i></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="status-message"></div>
          <div class="ajax-content-outer">
            <div class="ajax-content-inner"></div>
            <div class="project-navigation nav-arrows"><a href="#" class="nextProject"><span class="nav-arrow-next"></span></a><a href="#" class="prevProject"><span class="nav-arrow-prev"></span></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Ajax Section-->
      <ul id="isotope" class="portfolio isotope">
        <li class="item videography">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/05.jpg" alt="Extreme Freestyle" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=0" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/05.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Extreme Freestyle" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Extreme Freestyle</h4><span>Mood is a crucial component of well-being. It is an emotional state that can be influenced by personality or a variety of specific circumstances. This sub-category identifies worry, anxiety, happiness, mood fluctuations, and fatigue. Monitoring and managing mood can be vital for a student with regard to their life in general and school success.</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item photography width2x height2x">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/11asw5.jpg" alt="Looking at The Horizon" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=1" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/11asw5.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Looking at The Horizon" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Looking at The Horizon</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item photography design">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/wr4c5.jpg" alt="Design Studio" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=2" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/wr4c5.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Design Studio" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Design Studio</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item design">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/mac.jpg" alt="Minimalist Design" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=3" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/mac.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Minimalist Design" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Minimalist Design</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item branding width2x">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/2048asxsax.jpg" alt="Business Card" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=4" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/2048asxsax.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Business Card" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Business Card</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item branding">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/20aaaaa48.jpg" alt="Horst brand identity" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=5" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/20aaaaa48.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Horst brand identity" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Horst brand identity</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item design photography">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/20sshsh48.jpg" alt="Infinity Mirror" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=6" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/20sshsh48.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Infinity Mirror" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Infinity Mirror</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="item design">
          <!-- images should be in 1:1 format or multiples (2:1. 1:2, ...)--><img src="img/portfolio/247610222_460fa350b6_o.jpg" alt="Simple Desk Design" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="mask">
            <div class="mask-content">
              <div class="mask-wrapper text-center"><a href="#!/portfolio/project.html?i=7" class="info ajax_load"><i class="fa fa-link fa-border"></i></a><a href="img/portfolio/247610222_460fa350b6_o.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="Simple Desk Design" class="info"><i class="fa fa-expand fa-border"></i></a>
                <h4 class="upper">Simple Desk Design</h4><span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

And all I have done to create the second portfolio is copy and paste that code. I am stuck and have tried to resolve the issue in a number of ways, but I have still not been able to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that can do as you like. Try this one https://github.com/sapegin/jquery.mosaicflow